# UTF-8 in a Java applet (in a webpage)

Tags: java, html, utf-8

Perhaps this has never been asked because it's so trivial but: I have an old Java applet that I need to use on a slightly less old webpage. The applet, among other things, needs to read text from some files and display it to the user.
The files need to be in UTF-8, and the page that embeds the applet needs a UTF-8 encoding - and here's the problem: the applet won't display UTF-8 correctly under Windows (it's ok under Linux, though - Firefox, because Chrome plainly hates Java).

So, the question is: is there any way of suggesting the encoding to the applet (*without* recompiling it, because sources may not be available)?

Comment: Perhaps this thread can help you
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding

Comment: Thank you for the input but I was trying to do it without recompiling and, as far as I can tell, all of those solutions require to do just that.